# R SpatialPolygon Length Axes

Tags: r, r-sp

I have a SpatialPolygonDataframe, containing around 80 polygons that resemble the shape of individual trees that I am analyzing and need to calculate the maximum length or main axis and the length perpendicular to it (corresponding to the crown widths) of the contained polygons. 
One idea I had, or how I would solve this in ArcMap, would be to fit a rectangle around the polygons, but I don't know how to write this in R.

Cheers

Comment: Please include a sample of your data, example code of what you have tried and the exact bit you are having trouble with/getting an error with

Comment: I could upload a shapefile but firstly don't know how to and secondly think that it would not help a lot. I have a normal spatialpolygondatafram containing ~80 polygons and don't know to get the parameters I need. I couldn't find any function that fits...

Comment: type`dput(your-data)` and paste in the output, that's usually the way to go